# CreateSymbolicLink equivalent to “mklink /J”?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

Without admin privileges, I know I can create a symbolic link in command line:

mklink /J LinkPath OriginalResourcePath

In C++, I tried using CreateSymbolicLink; however, I got error "A required privilege is not held by the client." Is there a way to create a symlink/junction to a directory without admin privileges, equipvalent to mklink /j?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question has 3 not constructive close votes. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are creating with `mklink /j` is not a symbolic link. It is an NTFS junction. You can create junctions without admin rights, but you need `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege` to create a symbolic link. And by default only admin tokens have `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege`.

So, you need to create a junction. This Code Project article shows you how to do that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194/Windows-2000-Junction-Points

Comment: Thanks for that "by default". It blows at least one tiny bit of cloud off the sky of my general "this world is beyond repair" spleen. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. [`Junction`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) and GnuWin32's [`ln`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) work well on Windows, I use them all the time without elevation.

But regular file system access check apply. Your program must have write access to the directory to create a link.